# accessing array with gcsize objects

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsarray

I want to create different size of cell in an collectionview. In the **collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath** I created an array with **CGSize** objects. When I want to retrieve the objects stored in the NSArray (the same with NSMutableArray) I get the following semantic issue:

```
Returning 'id' from a function with incompatible result type 'CGSize' (aka 'struct CGSize')
```

How do I access my CGSize Objects in the array?

Edit: I figures out that the values stored in the array are from the type NSSize.

```c
-(CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UIImage *image;
    int row = [indexPath row];


    NSArray *mElements = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSValue valueWithCGSize:CGSizeMake(306.0, 270.0)],
                                [NSValue valueWithCGSize:CGSizeMake(100.0, 150.0)],
                                [NSValue valueWithCGSize:CGSizeMake(200.0, 150.0)],
                                [NSValue valueWithCGSize:CGSizeMake(200.0, 150.0)],
                                [NSValue valueWithCGSize:CGSizeMake(100.0, 150.0)],
                                nil];

    return [mElements objectAtIndex:row]; // Semantic issue

}
```

The thing I do not understand is, in another part the same approach works...

```c
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    CollectionViewCell *myCell = (CollectionViewCell *)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:Cellid forIndexPath:indexPath];

    int row = [indexPath row];

    myCell.cellImageView.image = [self.searches objectAtIndex:row];  // Here it works...
    return myCell;
}
```

Why does it work for an array with UIImages and not for an array with CGSize objects?

cheers -- jerik

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why does it work for an array with UIImages and not for an array with CGSize objects?

Because `UIImage`s **are** objects, `CGSize`s **are not objects.** (*But you could and should have looked this up in their respective documentation, really...*)

It would be pretty much enough if you tried to understand the error message. Your array contains objects (of type `NSValue *`) and not `CGSize` structs. So you cannot directly return an object from the array. You have to take the `NSValue` object and extract the `CGSize` struct from it:

```
return [[mElements objectAtIndex:row] CGSizeValue];
```

Comment: trying your code, throws a SIGABRT.

I wanted to check this with `NSLog(@"size: %@", [[magazinElements objectAtIndex:row] CGSizeValue]);` and got this issue message: `Format specifies type 'id' but the argument has type 'CGSize' (aka 'struct CGSize')`

Comment: @jerik Not my fault. You've done something inconsistent then. This code is correct.

Comment: Relax... my problem is that I do not get the element at the index (e.g. 0) from the array. If I have the element I can do stuff.

Answer (score 0):

SIGABRT was thrown because my iterating array was longer than the defined mElements array. Now it works.